# Does TCB(thread control block) is created even if the process is composed of only on thread(the process itself)?

Tags: multithreading, unix, process

According to the fact that given a single process a thread always exists(the process itself); when the process is created(and its PCB) is TCB created regardless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the fact that given a single process a thread always exists

You can have a process with no threads. This is when the process has terminated but its parent hasn't `wait`ed on it yet to extract the return code.

---

> is TCB created regardless

On Linux, it is created regardless. It is required by thread-local storage implementation which can be used in a single-threaded process. See [ELF Handling For Thread-Local Storage](https://akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf)
 for full details:

> At program start time the TCB along with the dynamic thread vector is created for the main thread.